# How to set a <div> style in reaction to a Vue.js data member change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, vue.js

## Summary

I would like a `<div>` to be square (`height` equal to `width`) when the size of the parent `<div>` changes due to a change of its content (which can span one or more lines).

## Details

The element design is

[image]

My idea is to watch for the changes of the text ("some text here" above) and recalculate the `width` of the square (the one with "a" above) so that it is equal to the `height` of the parent container (the margins on the drawing above are for illustration and are normally equal to zero).

I was expecting the following code ([JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/r471wecr/)) to do the trick:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    text: "this is  some text<br>and some more"
  },
  watch: {
    text: function() {
      document.getElementById("square").style.width = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="square">
      a
    </div>
    <div v-html="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the width of the square is not updated.

**Is there something fundamentally flawed with this approach?**

I thought that this may be a matter of the new width not being ready yet in the watch so I tried to use `Vue.nextTick()` to defer the calculation but it did not solve the issue ([forked JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/x1m31cpm/)):

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    text: "this is  some text<br>and some more"
  },
  watch: {
    text: function() {
      Vue.nextTick(function() {
        document.getElementById("square").style.width = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use:

```
document.getElementById("square").setAttribute("style","width:"+ document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight + 'px')
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("square").style.width = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight
```

Then, in order to account for the chnage, `Vue.nextTick()` also needs to be used.

Finally, changes will be visible after a modification of `text`.

The modified JS code:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    text: ""
  },
  watch: {
    text: function() {
      Vue.nextTick(function() {
        document.getElementById("square").setAttribute("style","width:"+ document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight + 'px')
      })
    }
}
})

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.text = "this is  some text<br>and some more"
}, 3000)
```

and its [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/fr5zd51m/).

Comment: I tried to use `setAttribute()` but it does not change the result. Also, in your JSFiddle I do not see the `div` containing "a" being a square?

Comment: it is when you will update text once again after change of height

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I just found out. If you are fine with that, I will edit your answer with code & JSFiddle  and accept it. `nextTick` is also needed.

Comment: I was going to do that :) Yes, you can update my answer

Comment: Glad it helped. This thing was just small issue to finish it